# multiple implicit joins and explicit joins in a query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have a query:

```
SELECT THDR.FILENAME,
       SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD AS TXN_SOURCE_CD,
       SOURCE.DESCR as TXN_SOURCE,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_EXT_ID,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_DTTM,
       THDR.UPLOAD_DTTM,
       L.DESCR,
       NVL(SUM(TDTL.TXN_VOL), 0) TOTAL_VOLUME
  FROM ci_lookup_val_l L,
       ci_txn_source_l source,
       CI_TXN_HEADER   THDR
  LEFT JOIN ci_txn_detail TDTL 
  ON THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID = TDTL.TXN_HEADER_ID        

 WHERE TRIM(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD) = TRIM(TDTL.TXN_SOURCE_CD)
   AND SOURCE.LANGUAGE_CD = 'ENG'      
   AND L.FIELD_NAME = 'TXN_HEADER_STATUS'
   AND THDR.BO_STATUS_CD = L.FIELD_VALUE
   AND L.LANGUAGE_CD = 'ENG'
   AND THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID='22222228'
 GROUP BY THDR.FILENAME,SOURCE.DESCR,THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID,THDR.TXN_HEADER_EXT_ID,THDR.TXN_HEADER_DTTM,THDR.UPLOAD_DTTM,L.DESCR,SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD
```

As you can see, this query has multiple implicit joins and 1 explicit join. This is the first time that I have used this kind of a query but it compiles. However, the left join in this query does not work. That is, if I have no record in TDTL corresponding to the record on THDR, the query does not return any rows.

Can you help me fix it?

Comment: if you read the question properly, you will find that the query does not give any error message but fetches erroneous data!

Comment: Remove the WHERE, verify your JOINS are actually joining as expected then put it back one condition at a time. No way anyone can answer this without a data sample and a detailed comparison between the expected and actual results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to change your query to use explicit joins for every one:

```
SELECT THDR.FILENAME,
       SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD AS TXN_SOURCE_CD,
       SOURCE.DESCR as TXN_SOURCE,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_EXT_ID,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_DTTM,
       THDR.UPLOAD_DTTM,
       L.DESCR,
       NVL(SUM(TDTL.TXN_VOL), 0) TOTAL_VOLUME
FROM ci_lookup_val_l L
INNER JOIN CI_TXN_HEADER   THDR
  ON THDR.BO_STATUS_CD = L.FIELD_VALUE
LEFT JOIN ci_txn_detail TDTL 
  ON THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID = TDTL.TXN_HEADER_ID       
LEFT JOIN ci_txn_source_l source
  on TRIM(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD) = TRIM(TDTL.TXN_SOURCE_CD)
  AND SOURCE.LANGUAGE_CD = 'ENG' 
WHERE L.FIELD_NAME = 'TXN_HEADER_STATUS' 
   AND L.LANGUAGE_CD = 'ENG'
   AND THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID='22222228'
GROUP BY THDR.FILENAME,
  SOURCE.DESCR,
  THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID,
  THDR.TXN_HEADER_EXT_ID,
  THDR.TXN_HEADER_DTTM,
  THDR.UPLOAD_DTTM,
  L.DESCR,
  SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD
```

Comment: this does not work because of the TRIM used. incorporate the answer by swap to correct urs

Comment: @MozenRath Can you elaborate on does not work?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: i dont get any rows. which means that some left join is not working correctly

Comment: @MozenRath I moved the `SOURCE.LANGUAGE_CD = 'ENG'` to the join condition since it would cause that to act like an `INNER JOIN`. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this condition:

```
 WHERE TRIM(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD) = TRIM(TDTL.TXN_SOURCE_CD)
```

When there's no matching entry in `TDTL`, `TDTL.TXN_SOURCE_CD` will be `NULL`, and the record will be rejected.

You need to rethink the (implicit inner) join that involves `SOURCE`.

Comment: does not work for the IS NULL, and not sure how to move the condition to left join

Answer (score 1):

you can use following clause in statment ,

```
WHERE TRIM(NVL(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD, 'NULL')) = TRIM(NVL(TDTL.TXN_SOURCE_CD, 'NULL'))
```

If you want to also check for null value. see if this works

Answer (score 1):

It's rather hard to follow, but it switching to use consistent join syntax helps a little. Providing data and expected results would help, so this is largely a guess. But the problem seems to be with:

```
WHERE TRIM(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD) = TRIM(TDTL.TXN_SOURCE_CD)
```

Since that is enforcing an inner-join condition between `SOURCE` and `TDTL`, the left out-join between `THDR` and `TDTL` is effectively becoming an inner join as well. You really need to move that into the outer join as well.

Something like this looks like it ought to give what you want, but still really not much more than a guess:

```
SELECT THDR.FILENAME,
       SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD AS TXN_SOURCE_CD,
       SOURCE.DESCR as TXN_SOURCE,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_EXT_ID,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_DTTM,
       THDR.UPLOAD_DTTM,
       L.DESCR,
       NVL(SUM(TDTL.TXN_VOL), 0) TOTAL_VOLUME
  FROM ci_lookup_val_l L
  JOIN ci_txn_source_l SOURCE
    ON SOURCE.LANGUAGE_CD = L.LANGUAGE_CD
  JOIN CI_TXN_HEADER THDR
    ON THDR.BO_STATUS_CD = L.FIELD_VALUE
  LEFT JOIN ci_txn_detail TDTL 
    ON TDTL.TXN_HEADER_ID = THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID        
   AND TRIM(TDTL.TXN_SOURCE_CD) = TRIM(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD)
 WHERE L.FIELD_NAME = 'TXN_HEADER_STATUS'
   AND L.LANGUAGE_CD = 'ENG'
   AND THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID = '22222228'
 GROUP BY THDR.FILENAME,SOURCE.DESCR,THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID,THDR.TXN_HEADER_EXT_ID,
           THDR.TXN_HEADER_DTTM,THDR.UPLOAD_DTTM,L.DESCR,SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD;
```

But if `TRIM(TDTL.TXN_SOURCE_CD)` or `TRIM(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD)` could be null then that comparison won't work, but it isn't at all clear what you'd want to happen. You could do:

```
  LEFT JOIN ci_txn_detail TDTL 
    ON TDTL.TXN_HEADER_ID = THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID        
   AND ((TRIM(TDTL.TXN_SOURCE_CD) IS NULL AND TRIM(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD) IS NULL)
       OR (TRIM(TDTL.TXN_SOURCE_CD) = TRIM(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD)))
```

... but really not sure that will give the answer you expect (whatever that is!).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all guys who answered the question. I have combined the suggestions made by most answers to find the actual solution:

```
SELECT THDR.FILENAME,
       SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD AS TXN_SOURCE_CD,
       SOURCE.DESCR as TXN_SOURCE,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_EXT_ID,
       THDR.TXN_HEADER_DTTM,
       THDR.UPLOAD_DTTM,
       L.DESCR,
       NVL(SUM(TDTL.TXN_VOL), 0) TOTAL_VOLUME
  FROM ci_lookup_val_l L,
       CI_TXN_HEADER   THDR
  LEFT JOIN ci_txn_detail TDTL 
  ON THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID = TDTL.TXN_HEADER_ID        
  LEFT JOIN ci_txn_source_l source
  ON (TRIM(NVL(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD, 'NULL')) = TRIM(NVL(TDTL.TXN_SOURCE_CD, 'NULL')) AND SOURCE.LANGUAGE_CD = :LANGUAGE)

 WHERE L.FIELD_NAME = 'TXN_HEADER_STATUS'
   AND THDR.BO_STATUS_CD = L.FIELD_VALUE
   AND L.LANGUAGE_CD = :LANGUAGE

 GROUP BY THDR.FILENAME,SOURCE.DESCR,THDR.TXN_HEADER_ID,THDR.TXN_HEADER_EXT_ID,THDR.TXN_HEADER_DTTM,THDR.UPLOAD_DTTM,L.DESCR,SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD;
```

Comment: What do you mean by this- `NVL(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD, NULL)` ? it's as if you say "if SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD is null then return null", or am I missing something... Did you mean perhaps- `NVL(SOURCE.TXN_SOURCE_CD, 'NULL')`

Comment: sry you are right my bad

Comment: Why is it now a left join to `SOURCE`? Won't that mean that `TXN_SOURCE_ID` and `TXN_SOURCE_CD` will be blank if there are no matching `TDTL` records?

Comment: yes. that is how it is desired